# Execute button function without touching it in Kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy

I just swaped from Tkinter to Kivy. In Tkinter I was able to execute the function binded to a button without pressing the button. I executed the function of a button with:

```
    button.invoke()
```

I know that it is possible to bind functions in Kivy with `on_press:` but is it also possible to execute the button function without actually pressing the button?

Greetings from Germany

Comment: Isn't possible I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`trigger_action`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.button.ButtonBehavior.trigger_action) method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        self.b1 = Button(text="Button 1", on_press=self.on_press_button_1)
        self.b2 = Button(text="Button 1", on_press=self.on_press_button_2)
        layout.add_widget(self.b1)
        layout.add_widget(self.b2)
        return layout

    def on_press_button_1(self, *args):
        print("on press button 1")

    def on_press_button_2(self, *args):
        self.b1.trigger_action(0)
        print("on press button 2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```